# How do I run a third-party command-line utility from AppleScript?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, macos-catalina

I downloaded a command line utility called [`dockutil`](https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil) which allows me to edit the Dock.

The command `dockutil --remove 'AirDrop'` works correctly when run from the command line (it removes a folder called "AirDrop" from the Dock). However I can't get it to run from within AppleScript.

I tried `do shell script "dockutil --remove 'AirDrop'"`, but I got `error "sh: dockutil: command not found" number 127`. I also tried saving it as a file and making it executable, but that didn't work either.

**How do I run this command from within AppleScript?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *target file* being *executed* is not within the `PATH` used by the `do shell script` *command*, which is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, then you need to use its *fully qualified pathname*, e.g.:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/dockutil --remove 'AirDrop'"
```

Comment: You learn a new thing every day